# Долгое определение местоположения

Tags: android, android-studio

Пишу приложение для определения текущего местоположения по нажатию на кнопку.
При нажатии ставлю `requestLocationUpdates` и в `onLocationChanged` вывожу название улицы по полученным координатам, а затем останавливаю поиск - `removeUpdates`. Все работает, только медленно. Иногда срабатывает моментально, а иногда уходит секунд 5-10, хотя подключен через Wi-Fi к интернету.

P.S: параллельно со слушателем GPS, ставлю еще и Network.

Есть ли варианты ускорить поиск? `GetLastKnownLocation` не подходит, ибо координаты не всегда верные.